# No resource found that matches the given name (styles)

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a new style to my styles.xml file.

I wrote this in res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="spinnerSettings"> 
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

When i try to add my style to a spinner (created inside res/layout/activity_settings.xml)

```
 <Spinner
    style="@styles/spinnerSettings"     
    android:id="@+id/levelSpinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"       
    android:drawSelectorOnTop = "true" />
```

I get this error:

**error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@styles/spinnerSettings')**

here `style="@styles/spinnerSettings"`

Comment: Try going to `File -> Save All`, and the `Project -> Clean`

Comment: I already tried it, but it's not working. Plus, if i clean the project my R.java file is deleted and not generated again! Thanks god i saved it before cleaning. I googled how to solve the R.java problems, but no one of the solutions I tried on the internet works for me

Comment: Fyi, the reason the R file wouldn't generate again is because the clean didn't work and your layout is still throwing errors. Once the errors are fixed the R file magically comes back :D

Comment: No no! I delete the line of code that gave me that error, and then i tried to clean the project! My R.java is not generated even when there isn't any error in my project. This is the first time i have this problem with R.java. I deleted it 10000000 times in my other projects, and Eclipse always re-created it without problems

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali If R.java isn't created, you have another problem somewhere in your xml. Check the problems tab

Comment: Thanks everybody. Anyway my main problem is to understand why eclipse tells me it can find the style i created in styles.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `style="@style/spinnerSettings"` (without `s` on the end)